# Rails where date is greater than given date query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to search where movies coming out have a release date greater than today's date

```
 Movie.where('release > ?', Date.today)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::ParseError: You have an error in your SQL     syntax;    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release > '2011-09-25')' at line 1: SELECT `movies`.* FROM `movies` WHERE (release > '2011-09-25')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you do greater than comparison on a date in a Rails 3 search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224600/can-you-do-greater-than-comparison-on-a-date-in-a-rails-3-search)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

## Rails 3+ :

```rb
Movie.where('release > ?', DateTime.now)
```

---

## Pre Rails 3

```rb
Movie.where(['release > ?', DateTime.now])
```

Comment: you don't need the array syntax for this anymore. rails 3, 4 :)

Comment: please elaborate @oma

Comment: @AdamWaite, meaning that the syntax in the Q is actually correct for newer versions

Comment: Note that if your query param is a `Date` and not a `DateTime`, then you'll likely want to call `.to_time` on the param. This will take into account the common difference between your Rails `Time.zone` (e.g. UTC-5) and your database time zone (should be UTC). So your query would look like: `Movie.where('release > ?', my_date.to_time)`. Aside: You can view your Postgres timezone using: `show timezone;`

Answer (score 41):

In recent versions of rails, you can do this:

```
User.where(created_at: 3.days.ago..Time.now)
```

See some other examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24150094

Comment: This is really nice @Patrick. FWIW if you want an **exclusive** date range, add a 3rd dot in the range, i.e. `User.where(created_at: 3.days.ago...Time.now)` and it works just as you'd expect.

Comment: You can also do `User.where(created_at: ..Time.now)` to leave the lower bound un-bounded. I.e. it would find anything that was created_at a time before Time.now.

Answer (score 17):

### Update

Rails core team decided to revert this change for a while, in order to discuss it in more detail. See [this comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39613#issuecomment-659553274) and [this PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39863) for more info.

I am leaving my answer only for educational purposes.

---

### new 'syntax' for comparison in Rails 6.1 (Reverted)

```rb
Movie.where('release >': DateTime.now)
```

Here is [a link to PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39613) where you can find more examples.

Comment: Thanks for keeping this up. Although it got reverted (not merged yet), I still find it a cool and super interesting read.

Answer (score 16):

In Ruby 2.7, you can try this:

```
License.where(expiration: Time.zone.today..)
```

```
SELECT "licenses".* FROM "licenses" WHERE "licenses"."expiration" >= '2021-07-06 15:12:05'
```

Answer (score 4):

Ruby [beginless/endless](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Range.html) ranges can also be used as an out-of-the-box solution:

`Post.where(id: 1..)`

=>   `Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" >= $1  [["id", 1]]`

`Post.where(id: ..9)`

=>   `Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" <= $1  [["id", 9]]`

`Post.where(id: ...9)`

=>   `Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" < $1  [["id", 9]]`

## Note:

Replace `id` with your date column `release`

Replace value with `Date.today`

Answer (score 0):

```
  Movie.where(release: Date.tomorrow..)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the extra value brought by this answer on top of [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64807328)?

Comment: Patrick's generated SQL would use `BETWEEN`, this wasn't what OP originally asked for (this will use `>=`). This answer shows how to pick a date in the future as the OP asked for.  And, this answer uses the same Model and attribute names that the OP used.

Comment: This makes sense to me. Would be great to have your help in moving the explanation from the comment into the answer in favour of future readers.