# How do I search for a date field after or before a certain date in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I know I can use a range to search where a date lies between 2 dates. For example:

```
User.where(:created_at => start_date..end_date )
```

But how would I do an open ended search for all dates before or after a date?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you do greater than comparison on a date in a Rails 3 search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224600/can-you-do-greater-than-comparison-on-a-date-in-a-rails-3-search)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply to this :

```
User.where("created_at >= ?", start_date )
```

Or this

```
User.where("created_at <= ?", end_date )
```