# Compare dates along with other constraints in ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to grab space listing date which is greater than another date.

So far, I have...

```
    Booking.where({ space_listing_id: 22, approved_status: true, ['move_out < ?', potential_move_in] })
```

I need to check if the Booking potential date is greater than each space_listing with move_out date.

My move_out and move_in is a datetime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4224627/2545197 this answer should help

Comment: Thanks Abhinay. it is working now. I did Booking.where("move_out < ?", potential_move_in).where({space_listing_id: 22, approved_status: true})

Comment: With another `where` query..answer to your question is there itself.

Comment: Thank you, Abhinay.

Comment: Also, `{ }` are optional, you can safely avoid them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to combine multiple constraints in an ActiveRecord query, you can simply use multiple `where` clause.

```
Booking.where(space_listing_id: 22, approved_status: true).where("move_out < ?", potential_move_in)
```